# Locally finite compact metric space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

If X is a compact metric space and A a part of X. The definition of locally finite for A is: For all $x\in$X, $\exists \epsilon$ such as $B(x,\epsilon)$ only contains a finite number of points of A.

My question is: does this still stands if by "For all x$\in$X" we write "For all x$\in$A"?

I think it does not but i can't seem to prove it

Comment: Let $X=\{0\}\cup\left\{\frac{1}n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}$ with the usual metric and $A=X\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there a way to show it for any X and A?

Comment: If $X$ is $T_1$, it's going to fail whenever $A$ is not closed in $X$: It will fail at limit points.

Comment: $A$ is locally finite with respect to itself iff it's a discrete subspace of $X$; it's locally finite with respect to $X$ iff it's a closed, discrete subspace of $X$.